# How can I tell what a bug in a program is if I'm very new to programming?

Tags: java

I read a question on here saying that you can contribute to open source code by seeking out bugs.  My question is, how can I tell what's a bug and what's not, if I just started learning to code?

**Clarification on the question** 
I was told to become a better coder, the best thing to do is to contribute to open source coding.  After searching for how to do that, the responses I found was to start with finding bugs.  There was no question posed on how to recognize bugs, so I inquired. I have received wonderful answers but now, I fearI am so new to SO that I don't know how to close the question out.**

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected, crashes as not expected, and quacks like a bug, then it's probably a bug :-)

Comment: Always big fun are [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most projects have a bug tracking system - a web page where you can lookup a list of the bugs and other issues that have been found in the project.

Before you start working on bugs, make sure you familiarize yourself with the particular project that you want to work on. Contact the developers of the project, find out what the planning is, ask them how you could help on the project, find out what the coding standards are, and what procedures you'll need to follow to submit a bugfix.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate all of the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get familiar with project. To find out new bugs, start using or running the program. If you run into some unexpected behavior you have encountered bug. Then you will have to try to find out place in source where this might be occurring.

An easier approach to contribute could be to look at bug list. Most projects maintain issue list which show existing bugs you can browse and see if you can resolve it.

Once you have solution you can submit patch and have it accepted in the project.